# Как создать свою функцию прототип для массива в TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Изучаю TypeScript, сразу к делу:
Я пытаюсь создать функцию, которую можно будет вызвать в массиве.
Пример:

```js
[1, 2, 3].f();
```

Сам код на TypeScript:

```
Array.prototype.f = () => 5;
```

Но вот незадача, VS Code сообщает мне такую ошибку:

> Свойство "f" не существует в типе "any[]".

Что делать? На название функции не обращайте внимания, это просто тест.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

модификация **встроенных** классов считается плохим подходом.

есть как минимум два способа избежать этого.

### вариант [Раз](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAJAtgSwB5QLxQDwBUA0UCyUESwEAdgCYDOUA3gL4B8AFAIYBO7AXFLlIkgRke+AJRpGvKADICAbgBQAYwD2ZKsH7Ie8ZGihs8ccakkB5AEYArCEuAA6VlSoIA5mUP9RC5Wo1QOdn0AbQBGPAAmPABmAF1fdU0BIX1aBSgMqCoAVzhmYAALBCoeMlyLCHZg2PE0zPqodghgbPYyKELi+yaKbKUIZk8LE0lWKABqKGH0zPoFOYT-YlJKCAoAQU59ATZOI2Qhb1VErNz9ZfIKNc32exy8o78VABsIe2eVV2Z77yA):

```
type $mix = <T, M extends {}>(arr: T, mixin: M) => T & M;
const mix: $mix = (a, m) => Object.assign(a, m)

const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const mixin = {
    sum(this: number[]) {
        return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    }
}

const extendedArr = mix(arr, mixin)
const sum = extendedArr.sum()
console.log(sum)
```

```js
"use strict";
const mix = (a, m) => Object.assign(a, m);
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const mixin = {
    sum() {
        return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    }
};
const extendedArr = mix(arr, mixin);
const sum = extendedArr.sum();
console.log(sum);
```

### вариант Два:

создать новый класс, расширяющий базовый.

### P.S.

для углубления рекомендую изучить такие библиотеки как: *lodash*, *JQuery*.

Answer (score 1):

Спросил у знакомого, он сказал что нужно использовать интерфейсы.

```
interface Array<T> {
    f(): number
}

Array.prototype.f = () => 5;
```